# Create an SSB (Site Specific Browser) using .NET

Tags: .net, browser

I am trying to create a site specific browser using .NET. I have googled much about this and only came across Prism, Mozilla's SSB implementation. I was realling hoping for a codeproject article but till now, no luck.

So I would like to get any sort of pointers, tutorials or any info on creating a new SSB with .NET as development platform. Also what all browser engines support creation of an SSB?